# Error in independet test: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, permutation

I have a problem with my data maybe, but I don`t see it by myself.
I have data with many columns and 5 factors (rows). I want to do permutation anova test to one of the columns and all factors. But when I do this I get an error.

this is the head of my data, I am interesting in CTWF column

```
 Worm_Names  Area Length Thickness MidWidth  Head  Tail Number_of_Peaks Mean_Peak_Inten~ STD_Peak_Intens~  CTWF Head_CTWF Tail_CTWF
  <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 ev         3289.   156.      21.1     21.3 0.666 0.688              20             3.36             1.64 4120.      273.      217.
2 ev         1810.   112.      16.2     13.8 0.846 1.06               11             2.81             1.57 1722.      112.      240.
3 ev         2473.   132.      18.8     18.5 0.764 0.794              13             3.02             1.77 2895.      265.      208.
4 ev         2969.   161.      18.4     19.5 0.667 1.03               15             2.80             2.06 3929.      185.      253.
5 ev         2397.   135.      17.7     16.5 0.776 0.635              14             2.44             1.70 3007.      253.      223.
6 ev         2324.   150.      15.4     16.1 0.818 0.649              13             2.53             1.87 2600.      248.      179.
```

this is my code

```
CF2260_GPI_ = independence_test(CF2260_GPI$CTWF ~ CF$Worm_Names)
```

and that what I get

```
 error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :arguments imply differing number of rows: 538, 1017
```

If somebody can help me with that?
Thank you!

Comment: Which package are you using?  Please add your input data to your question using `dput(CF2260_GPI)` or `dput(head(CF2260_GPI))`.

Comment: you are testing columns from different data frames, is this what you intended?

Comment: I don`t know what to say, sometimes we need a fresh look at our data. Thank you for the help, my fault was with different data frames...